# Memory error while using selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Recently, I'm trying to scrape a waterfall website through Selenium (request doesn't work and I can't get the API).

However, I came across a problem that I can't solve: Memory error.

Because using Selenium is really ram consuming, I had tried to appoint my USB function as cache through the following code

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=F:\OuoC')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chromedriver.exe',options = options)
```

Yet, this failed to work. When I open my USB, though I saw the files added by selenium, chrome driver still consumes my computer's built in ram, and the files in USB weren't refreshing either(I had pressed f5).

Besides, my Anaconda prompt also shown the following message:

```
[10320:11384:0202/231331.035:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [23:13:31.035] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: 
(0x1F)
[I 23:15:25.741 NotebookApp] Saving file at /play/ques.ipynb
```

Comment: which OS are you using

Comment: I'm using win10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=F:\OuoC')
```

is not a step to set cache but to set the profile user-data , this has nothing to do with RAM . RAM is used to store data temporarly for faster processing as it supports faster input and output signals.

so,

```
   options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=F:\OuoC')
```

will just use your usb instead of your hard disk. You can use this method if your harddisk space is less.

**For saving RAM few things you could do is ,**

1. Use readyboost in windows 10

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware-winpc/readyboost-for-windows-10/9aa6f86f-f77d-4d81-9853-8bae72a58098

2. Reduce execution time between steps by adding sleep

Slowing down chrome usage frees' up RAM , when execution is fast it takes up more RAM

3. Close chrome browser and restart browser in between your tests , use

This will clear RAM that is used by current chrome instance

Try these steps

Comment: Thank you very much ! Now I am working on it !

Comment: I used solution 2 and 3 for my question at last. My computer is using SSD, so I can't use readyboost.

Comment: @JImmy goto that pendriver  in my computer or this pc and click properties on the usb drive  , tthee should be ready boost option if i am not wrong

Comment: yes I saw boost options, but it says that I'm using ssd so it doesn't let me to use this function.